# Pulling out data when there are multiple rows with same description but different dates

Tags: sql, matching

I need to pull out the data where the need expires in the next month. Although the end_date may be in this range, there is another row for the person_code with the same need description, but a date in the future. I need a way to look at just the date that is in the future. The need is uniform and so will match up.

I can get out a list of people whose need expires within a month, but generally have another line against their ID that has a future date for the same need, so don't need to be on the list.

```
select  
eln.person_code, 
eln.END_DATE, 
Case when eln.NEED_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = 'Other' then eln.NEED_DESCRIPTION
Else eln.NEED_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
End As 'Access Requirement'

from EBS_LEARNER_NEEDS eln
JOIN EBS_LEARNER_NEEDS eln2 
    on eln.PERSON_CODE = eln2.PERSON_CODE
    and eln.NEED_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = eln2.NEED_TYPE_DESCRIPTION 
    and eln.END_DATE < eln2.END_DATE

where eln.END_DATE between getdate() and (dateadd(M,+1, Getdate())) 
order by eln.end_date desc
```

I need the result to be people with an expiring need to be listed, based on the future line date rather than the one with the date that is sooner.

There will be a lines like this
[Image of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LulpA.png)

I am trying to pull out records that have a end date in the next month, but need to ignore them if they already have a new row with a future date and matching person_code and Access Requirement.

I hope this makes sense

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of a colleague we managed to suss this using the having clause.

```
select 
eln.person_code, 
ISNULL(p.forename,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(p.surname,'') as 'Student',
eln.End_date,
Case when eln.NEED_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = 'Other' then eln.NEED_DESCRIPTION
Else eln.NEED_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
End As 'Access Requirement'

from EBS_LEARNER_NEEDS eln
JOIN PEOPLE p on p.PERSON_CODE = eln.PERSON_CODE

Group by eln.person_code, 
ISNULL(p.forename,'') + ' ' + ISNULL(p.surname,''), 
Case when eln.NEED_TYPE_DESCRIPTION = 'Other' then eln.NEED_DESCRIPTION
Else eln.NEED_TYPE_DESCRIPTION
End, eln.END_DATE
Having Max (eln.END_DATE) between getdate() and (dateadd(M,+1, Getdate()))
```